# "TypeError: String Indices must be integers" when using Twython

Tags: python, twitter, typeerror, hashtag, twython

I'm trying to get tweets by hashtags. It seems to load them but at the point to save the tweet id, I get:

```
"TypeError: String indices must be integers".
```

I think the problem is something like [this](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake).

My code:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import time
import math
import json

def twitter_oauth_login():
    API_KEY = ""
    API_SECRET = ""
    ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""
    twitter = Twython(API_KEY,API_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return(twitter)

twitter=twitter_oauth_login()

def get_minimum_id(list_of_tweets):
    ids = [] 
    idsproxy=[]
    for tweet in list_of_tweets:
        this_id = tweet['id'] #The problem appears here
        this_id = int(this_id) 
        print this_id
        ids.append(this_id) 
    if ids == idsproxy:
        minimum = 0
        return minimum
    else:
        minimum = min(ids) 
        return minimum 

def get_complete_timeline(hashtag):
     twitter = twitter_oauth_login()
     all_tweets = [] 
     max_id = None 
     while True: 
        new_tweets = twitter.search(q='#'+hashtag, count=200,    max_id=max_id)
        print u"Identified" + str(len(new_tweets)) + u" new tweet for user  " + hashtag
        all_tweets.extend(new_tweets) 

        print "Wait 10 seconds"
        time.sleep(10) 
        min_id = get_minimum_id(new_tweets) 
        max_id = min_id - 1 
        if len(new_tweets) < 100:
            break 
            print "Task complete: in total " + len(all_tweets) + " tweets were loaded."
     return all_tweets
```

The traceback:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-708b711e136b> in <module>()
 ----> 1 get_complete_timeline("omg")

<ipython-input-51-34204cb2269e> in get_complete_timeline(hashtag)
     42         print "Wait 10 seconds"
     43         time.sleep(10)
---> 44         min_id = get_minimum_id(new_tweets) 
     45         max_id = min_id - 1 
     46         if len(new_tweets) < 100:

<ipython-input-51-34204cb2269e> in get_minimum_id(list_of_tweets)
     19         for tweet in list_of_tweets: 
     20                 print '1'
---> 21                 this_id = tweet['id'] 
     22                 print '2'
     23                 this_id = int(this_id) 

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: could you please copy/paste the full stacktrace here? because TypeError can be raised by many lines in the script you posted :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `list_of_tweets`(or `new_tweets`) as returned from [`twitter.search`](http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/basic_usage.html?highlight=search#searching) is a  [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) Type.

You are not iterating correctly over the dictionary, just like in this example:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
for value in d:
   print value

# This would iterate over the dictionary keys
>> 'a'
>> 'b'
```

Correct iteration over dictionary is using the [`iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) method:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b': 2}
for key, value in d.iteritems():
   print key, value

>> 'a', 1
>> 'b', 2
```

To iterate over the statuses returned:

```
for tweet in list_of_tweets['statuses']:
    print tweet['id']
```